# Process standard output doesnt work in c# when i try to show it using git push origin <branch>

Tags: c#, git, unity-editor

When I try to do push I want to also redirect the result that it usually writes in the console like in git bash [THE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUFQJ.png)

```
string branchoutput;
            Process push = new Process();
            push.StartInfo.FileName = "git";
            push.StartInfo.Arguments = $"push origin {pushoutput} "; 
            push.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            push.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            push.Start();
            push.WaitForExit();
branchoutput = push.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
GUILayout.Label(branchoutput); //label that will show the result
```

but when I do it it doesnt show the result. It does the push but doesnt show the result.
It does show results when I do *git status* but not when you do commands that actually do something not just show things.

can anyone help with this?

Comment: Never call `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` after `WaitForExit`, this should became first